# I need help to change many links on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set up a very minimalist cashback website open to only some users. To track the users i thought of changing attributes to links like affExtParam and subid's to track which user made the transaction. My idea was to change the link by using an input box where the users would enter their name. So i used

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
              window.onload=function()
    {
         var el=document.getElementById('affiliate_0');
        el.onclick=function(){
            var my_text=prompt('Enter: Name - Email');
            if(my_text) window.open("http://affiliateaddress&subid1="+my_text)

        }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
          window.onload=function()
{
     var el=document.getElementById('affiliate_1');
    el.onclick=function(){
        var my_text=prompt('Enter: Name - Email');
        if(my_text) window.open("http://affiliateaddress="+my_text)

    }
}
      </script>
```

This worked only when there was one link on the page. When I made two of thiese scripts like the above, it didnt work.

Any help, suggestions are welcomed.

P.S. The users are fixed to a certain location. I dont know them personally.

Comment: why are you going with 2 script tags? All you need is one.

Comment: With second `window.onload=function()` call you override first call. You need to use jquery for this task, as solution may be a bit complicated in pure js.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're redefining window.onload twice, so only the second definition will run.

Answer (score 1):

Try including all your code in just one onload function. You'll need to rename some variables, since you're using the same names.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it inside a single `script` tag,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function()
    {
        var el=document.getElementById('affiliate_0');
        el.onclick=function(){
            var my_text=prompt('Enter: Name - Email');
            if(my_text)     
                window.open("http://affiliateaddress&subid1="+my_text)
        }

        var el2=document.getElementById('affiliate_1');
        el2.onclick=function(){
            var my_text=prompt('Enter: Name - Email');
            if(my_text)
                window.open("http://affiliateaddress="+my_text)
        }
    }
</script>
```

> This is not the cleanest way to achieve this. You should make this a
>   function which is generic and reusable. But your issue will be
>   resolved by following this.